# Tabla dinámica con AJAX

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, phpmyadmin

hola estroy trabajado con ajax y php , quiero hacer una tabla pero no estoy seguro de como devolver datos ajax a html o texto plano, agradecería mucho su ayuda :)

```html
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6">
        <h3>Lista</h3>
        <div id="tusers" class="table-hover table-responsive">

        </div>
      </div>
      
<script type="text/javascript">
// Llenar lista de usuarios
$(document).on("ready",function(){
  listaUsers();
});

var listaUsers = function (){
      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'listar.php',
        success: function(data){
          $('#tableUsers').html(data);
        }
      });
    }
  
</script>
```

Este en mi php ...

```html
<?php

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$bd= "kyo";

   $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password,$bd);

   $sql = "SELECT `username`, `mail`, `id` FROM `users` ";
   $res = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

     if(!$res){
       die("Error!!! ... D:");
     }else{
       while ($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res) ) {
         # code...
         $array["data"][] = $data;
       }
       echo json_encode($array);
     }

     mysqli_free_result($res);
     mysqli_close($conn);

 ?>
```

Les agradecería con una referencia o algún ejemplo de ayuda :D
Grácias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Saludos**

En base a lo que colocaste te comento que sería un JSON; en el *html*.

```
<html>
   [...]
   <script>
      /* Por lo que veo usas jQuery */
      function listarUsuarios() {
         $.ajax({
           type: 'POST',
           url: [urlRutayArchivo],
           dataType  : 'html',
           success: function(data){
             $('#tableUsers').html(data);
           }
         });
      }  // listarUsuarios

      /* Segun prefieras o estes más familiazado usa este */
      $(function () {
        listarUsuarios();
      }); 
      /* ó; deseable no dejes ambos solo uno */ 
      $(document).ready(function () {
        listarUsuarios();
      }); 

   </script>
   <body>
      [... inicio tu estructura como la necesite]
      <div id="tusers" class="table-hover table-responsive">

      </div>
      [... fin tu estructura como la necesite]
   </body>
</html>
```

Considerando que tu `html` que muestras no tienes como tal el `table` que corresponda a llenar, tendrás que armarlo desde el `php` y simplemente insertarlo en la `div` que para ello designas; en tu php (idea de orientación)*:

```
<?php
   /* Tu proceso de conexión, consulta y resultado */
   $res = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

   if(!$res){
       echo "Ocurrio un error en la consulta"; /* Si ocurre verifica todo lo tengas bien */
   }else{
       $tabla ="<table>";
       /* No olvide el THEAD y sus TD para formar el encabezado de la tabla */
       /* Contenido de la tabla */
       $tabla .="<tbody>";
       while ($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res) ) {
          $tabla .="<tr>";
             /* Un TD por cada datos que quieras mostrar; emj con el mail */
             $tabla .="<td>".$data["mail"]."</td>";
          $tabla .="</tr>";
       }
       $tabla .="</tbody>";
       $tabla .="</table>";
       echo tabla;
   }

   mysqli_free_result($res);
   mysqli_close($conn);

?>
```